# JQuery, Google Maps and $('#myId') == getElementById("myId")

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

Why this isn't true?

```
$('#myId') == document.getElementById("myId")
```

I'm using JQuery 1.4.2 and trying to insert a GMap into an div element.

So, this works:

```
new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("myId"),myOptions);
```

but this doesn't

```
new google.maps.Map($("myId"),myOptions);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have a couple issues. First, ID selectors use `#`. Second, `$(...)` is a jQuery object, and you need to pass a DOM element.

Use `$('#myId').get(0)`

[The get method.](http://docs.jquery.com/Get)

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't work because the `google.maps.Map()` constructor expects a a DOM element, while the jQuery selector returns a jQuery object.

You may want to use:

```
new google.maps.Map($("#myId")[0], myOptions);
```

Further reading:

- [Google Maps API Groups: Why doesn't jQuery selection work?](http://groups.google.com/group/google-maps-api/browse_thread/thread/9f1188edf912c3e2/b596e4686824e8da?pli=1)

Answer (score 1):

$('#myId') creates a jQuery selection, while GMap requires a DOM element.  You can convert the jQuery selection into a DOM element by using the $().get function:

```
new google.maps.Map($("#myId").get(0), myOptions);
```